# How to switch i and a in Sublime Text 2 Vintage Mode?

Tags: key, sublimetext2

i have switched my <kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>a</kbd> keys in vim. With this:

```
nnoremap i a
nnoremap a i
```

is it possible to switch them in Sublime Text 2 too?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex's answer is partially correct, but he is giving you the wrong command. You will want to take a look at the key binding file in the Vintage Package to get the proper command and context. Add the following to your user keybinding file instead.

```
{ "keys": ["a"], "command": "enter_insert_mode",
  "context":
  [
        {"key": "setting.command_mode"},
        {"key": "selection_empty"}
  ]
},{ "keys": ["i"], "command": "enter_insert_mode", "args":
    {"insert_command": "move", "insert_args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true} },
    "context":
    [
        {"key": "setting.command_mode"},
        {"key": "selection_empty"}
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Preferences -> Key bindings - User

Add

```
{ "keys": ["i"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "a"} },
{ "keys": ["a"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "i"} }
```

between the `[]`s.

Comment: but this does not enable the insert mode, if i type i in the command mode Sublime types an a and stayed in command mode (a is the same)